# How can I convert a hex string to a byte array in php

Tags: php, hex

Below is the c# implementation

```
using System;

public class Program
{
     void CanDecodeFromString(string str)
        {
            if (str.Length % 2 != 0)
                return;
            //OutputText("    " + "J1939:" + "\r\n");

            byte[] j1939data = new byte[str.Length / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length / 2; i++)
            {
                j1939data[i] = System.Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(2 * i, 2), 16);
            }
            //J1939DataDecode(j1939data);
         Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", j1939data));
        }
    public static void Main()
    {
        var p= new Program();
        p.CanDecodeFromString("31058F410C15E1310D48312F8F41310000630220290082");
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }

}
```

Python

```
hex_string="31058F410C15E1310D48312F8F41310000630220290082"
hex_data = hex_string.decode("hex")
import array
array.array('B', hex_data)
```

In php what is the proper way for it ?

The sample output

```
49
5
143
65
12
21
225
49
13
72
49
47
143
65
49
0
0
99
2
32
41
0
130
```

Comment: whats the sample output? [0x31, 0x05, 0x8F...]?

Comment: 49
5
143
65
12
21
225
49
13
72
49
47
143
65
49
0
0
99
2
32
41
0
130

Comment: Hi, you figured out how to do convert a long hex string to a byte array?